# renaming and moving files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add the string "XYZ" to each file name and then move my files from folderA to folderB.
This is the code that i have so far.

---

```
Private Const varSourceAddress As String = "\\serverA\drivename\FolderA\"
Dim diaddr As New DirectoryInfo(varSourceAddress)
Dim fiaddr As FileInfo() = diaddr.GetFiles()

While diaddr.GetFiles.Length > 0
  For Each scannedFile As FileInfo In fiaddr
    If scannedFile.Name.Contains("Thumbs") = False Then
      If scannedFile.Exists Then
         strOldName = scannedFile.Name
         strNewName = strOldName.Insert(14, "XYZ")
         scannedFile.CopyTo("\\serverA\drivename\FolderB\" & strNewName, True)
         scannedFile.Delete()

         strOldName = ""
         strNewName = ""

      End If
     End If
    Next
  End While
```

---

I am using this code in a windows service. When the service runs for the first time, everything happens the way its suppose to be. It does add XYZ to every file's name and the files get moved to folderB also. However, upon the second run, it sends an error message:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '\\serverA\drivename\folderA\20130327082003.pdf'.
```

I can see that the file `20130327082003.pdf` has already been moved to folderB with the new name of `20130327082003XYZ.pdf` and that is all fine, but the service keeps checking for the same file name in folderA.

I have tried rename, move, copy, copyto all these commands also, but instead of checking for the new files (if any) in folderA the system keeps checking for the file that has already been moved to folderB. Somehow the loop keeps referencing the last file that it has renamed(and already moved) to folderB.

I am using `.Delete` method to delete the file (or any reference) once it has been copied to folderB, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Once the service will be running, eventually it's suppose to move every new file generated in folderA (after adding XYZ to its name) to folderB.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: If you're going to check if the file exists and if it contains a string, shouldn't you be checking if it exists before you check if the name contains a string?

Comment: You are probably moving the file *before* the process that modifies it is done with it.  You'll need to obtain an exclusive lock on the file with FileShare.None.  Which will fail at first.  Try again later.

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops one inside the other, the external loop (while) continues until there are no more files returned by GetFiles(), but in the internal loop you use the variable `fiaddr`  obtained outside the loop.

I think you are looping more than it is necessary

```
Private Const varSourceAddress As String = "\\serverA\drivename\FolderA\"
Dim diaddr As New DirectoryInfo(varSourceAddress)
Dim fiaddr As FileInfo() = diaddr.GetFiles()

For Each scannedFile As FileInfo In fiaddr
    If scannedFile.Exists Then ' not sure it is necessary unless someone adds files externally
        If scannedFile.Name.Contains("Thumbs") = False Then
            strOldName = scannedFile.Name
            strNewName = strOldName.Insert(14, "XYZ")
            scannedFile.CopyTo("\\serverA\drivename\FolderB\" & strNewName, True)
            scannedFile.Delete()
            strOldName = ""
            strNewName = ""
        End If
    End If
 Next
```